# How to use ssh key in gftp?

Tags: ssh

I ssh to a remote server from command line using key to not enter password at any time want to connect. I need to transfer some files to the server using gFTP software.

Is it possible to use ssh key to connect to a remote server via gFTP in Ubuntu?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filezilla or WinSCP alternative for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987769/filezilla-or-winscp-alternative-for-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps how to setup gFTP to use SSH keys:

1. In the **FTP menu** click on **Preferences**;
2. Go to **SSH tab**;
3. Fill the field **SSH Extra Params** with this value:

   ```
   -o IdentityFile=/home/<your user>/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```

   Change `<user name>` with your **real username**. Or use:

   ```
   -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```
4. In gFTP's main window choice **SSH2** as type of the connection;
5. Enter the target **Host** name, or **IP** address;
6. Setup the SSH **Port** of the target machine (if it's not the default - `22`);
7. Enter **User** for the SSH connection;
8. Enter your SSH key's **Pass**phrase (if there is some);
9. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

[image]