# Filezilla or WinSCP alternative for Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, software-recommendation, ftp, sftp, filezilla

On Windows I'm using FileZilla to upload/download files on my WordPress website, via sftp, while using ssh key.

Now Linux is my primary operating system. For the last month FileZilla client was working fine on Ubuntu 16.04, but now it crashes whenever I start it. I search on internet and found that it is happening with a lot of users. Unfortunately the FileZilla support just have one answer if we ask them:

> Ubuntu 16.04 is old OS, use 17.10 or Debian latest version.

I don't want to use 17.10. So I am looking for FileZilla client alternative for Linux, which I can use as sftp client with ssh key.

I found gFTP (which is an old program and I'm not sure how much secure is it?), I also found that I can use Ubuntu file manager to connect to my server. Is that a good idea to connect to server while using Nautilus or Caja?

Actually I don't want to put my username / password in dialogue box which appear when I click File > Connect to server, instead I want to use my `.ppk` key. How I can add that in Nautilus or Caja?

Comment: I just want to further clear my question. Actually I don't want to put my username / password in dialogue box which appear when I click File > Connect to server, instead I want to use .ppk key. How I can add that in Nautilus or Caja?

Comment: You can connect via Nautilus (or another file manager) and create a bookmark, which makes things very convenient. See this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/964957/remote-access-ubuntu-server-filesystem-through-gui/964972#964972

Comment: "*until a month back filezilla client was working fine*" did you upgrade FZ?

Comment: @RonJohn Yes, I tried to do so but there is no update available for filezilla in ubuntu repo and I also downloaded latest version from filezilla site but that is not working with ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Typically, you can find older versions of software to download.

Comment: What's wrong with the version in the 16.04 repo?

Comment: It is Ubuntu rather than the Filezilla devs who are maintaining the branch of Filezilla for 16.04, so it's kind of natural that the Filezilla devs would simply tell you to upgrade, because they're not responsible for how the version in Ubuntu 16.04 behaves.  Try opening Filezilla from a terminal window so if it crashes you may get an error message or trace in the console, then compare it with the [existing reported bugs in Filezilla](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/filezilla/+bugs?orderby=-importance&start=0) and if new, make a new report.

Comment: its a marvel how ubuntu conveniently brakes old versions forcing ppl to upgrade; but thats what you get from having bleeding edge/unstable, you get a head bump with a baseball bat every 6 months..; try downgrade filezila

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/94665/what-is-a-program-similar-to-winscp and https://askubuntu.com/questions/109000/nicer-ftp-client-than-filezilla.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Using Nautilus

You can use the option `Connect to Server` in Nautilus as it is shown on the next image.

[image]

- *If you need to find the command-line path to the mounted directory use one of the approaches presented here: [CLI path to ftp network connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876398/cli-path-to-ftp-network-connection/876425#876425).*

1. The first example - `sftp://victoria-pass/home/tri` - uses predefined *host* called `victoria-pass` and mounts the `home/` directory of the remote user called `tri`.

   To use this approach, you should create user's configuration file for the local ssh client. The file must be called `config` and placed in the directory `.ssh/` in user's home: `~/.ssh/config`. According to the example the content of the file should be:

   ```bsh
   Host victoria-pass             # this is as 'nickname' of the connection
       HostName victoria.org      # or use the IP address
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa # or provide the fill path to another key
       User tri                   # use the actual name of the remote user
       Port 1111                  # provide the actual port of the remote server
       # other parameters...

   # setup each another Host in the same way...
   ```

   Change the file permissions:

   ```
   chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
   ```

   In addition, now you should be able to connect to each of these hosts by a command as:

   ```
   ssh victoria-pass
   ```
2. The second example - `sftp://tri@victoria.org:1111/home/tri` - shows how to connect to a remote ssh (sftp) server without using predefined `~/.ssh/config` file with a custom ssh port.

   The main cons of this approach is that if the authentication file is not `~/.ssh/id_rsa` you should provide it in advance by the command `ssh-add`. For example if the authentication file is called `file.pem`:

   ```
   ssh-add /full/path/to/the/authentication/file.pem
   ```

   I think you should do this every time when you restart the local machine, or you should include the above command in the `~/.profile` file.

---

## Usung gFTP

Here are the steps how to setup gFTP to use SSH keys.

[image]

1. In the **FTP menu** click on **Preferences**;
2. Go to **SSH tab**;
3. Fill the field **SSH Extra Params** with this value:

   ```
   -o IdentityFile=/home/<your user>/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```

   Change `<user name>` with your **real username**. Or use:

   ```
   -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```
4. In gFTP's main window choice **SSH2** as type of the connection;
5. Enter the target **Host** name, or **IP** address;
6. Setup the SSH **Port** of the target machine (if it's not the default - `22`);
7. Enter **User** for the SSH connection;
8. Enter your SSH key's **Pass**phrase (if there is some);
9. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

## Using SSHFS

You could mount a remote directory (or the entire file system) via the command-line tool `sshfs`. Then you could manipulate it "locally" as you wish. This is my preferable way. Let's assume the mounting directory is `~/mount` and you want to mount the remote user's home directory:

```
sshfs user@host.name.or.ip:/home/<user> /home/<local-user>/mount/
```

Or if you have created `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
sshfs host-name:/home/<remote-user> /home/<local-user>/mount/
```

In addition you could create also `/etc/fstab` entry - references:

- [How to convert sshfs command to fstab entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710149/how-to-convert-sshfs-command-to-fstab-entry)
- [sshfs is not mounting automatically at boot, despite /etc/fstab configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326977/sshfs-is-not-mounting-automatically-at-boot-despite-etc-fstab-configuration)

---

## Convert the PPK Key

Please note if you are previously have used *PPK* key, which means *PuTTY Private Key*, you should convert it because, unlike CloneZilla, the above tools can't read this format. For this purposes you should use the tool `puttygen` that is a part of the package `putty-tools`:

```
sudo apt install putty-tools
```

Now you can convert the key in this way:

```
puttygen input-key-filename.ppk -O private-openssh -o output-key-filename.pem
```

Thanks to [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) for this note. Here is the source and few additional references:

- [How to convert Filezilla PPK to openssh sftp compatible key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904142/how-to-convert-filezilla-ppk-to-openssh-sftp-compatible-key)
- [How to convert PuTTY's .ppk to SSH key](https://www.simplified.guide/putty/convert-ppk-to-ssh-key)
- [How to convert .ppk key to OpenSSH key under Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/232362/how-to-convert-ppk-key-to-openssh-key-under-linux/232365#232365)
- [How to SSH Ubuntu from Windows via PuTTY, using key](https://askubuntu.com/a/899416/566421)

---

## According to the security

While all approaches use the same method of connection - SSH - the security that they provide should be equivalent. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell):

> Secure Shell (SSH) is a cryptographic network protocol for operating
>   network services securely over an unsecured network... SSH provides a secure channel over an unsecured network in a
>   client-server architecture, connecting an SSH client application with
>   an SSH server...
>
> The encryption used by SSH is intended to provide confidentiality and
>   integrity of data over an unsecured network, such as the Internet... SSH uses public-key cryptography to authenticate the remote computer
>   and allow it to authenticate the user, if necessary...
>
> One way is to use automatically generated public-private key pairs to
>   simply encrypt a network connection, and then use password
>   authentication to log on...
>
> Another is to use a manually generated public-private key pair to
>   perform the authentication, allowing users or programs to log in
>   without having to specify a password. In this scenario, anyone can
>   produce a matching pair of different keys (public and private)...

Comment: thank you for your reply. actually I don't want to put my username / password in dialogue box which appear when I click File > Connect to server, instead I want to use .ppk key. How I can add that in Nautilus or Caja?

Comment: @ShahMoeen, I'm done.

Comment: @ShahMoeen please see [How to convert Filezilla PPK to openssh sftp compatible key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904142/how-to-convert-filezilla-ppk-to-openssh-sftp-compatible-key). Alternatively, if you still have access to Windows, [How to convert PuTTY's .ppk to SSH key](https://docs.oseems.com/general/application/putty/convert-ppk-to-ssh-key)

Comment: Thank you @pa4080 for your kind and detail reply. I did every step you ask with gFTP but unfortunately it didn't work. On main screen of gFTP after entering Host, Port and user details when I press enter, it started connecting but this never end, on bottom I can see it stop at " Protocol Initialization"

Comment: @steeldriver thank you so much, finally I did it with gFTP. Thank you everyone for your help, BTW will you people let me know which method you use and why??

Comment: @ShahMoeen, I use `ssh` and `sftp` from the command line most of the time. I know these commands since long ago (old unix commands) and they work well for me.