# Can my Ubuntu server have both FTP and SFTP installed

Tags: 14.04, ftp, sftp

I want to create an FTP user in an Ubuntu server and I also want the same user to access SFTP server in same machine. can I install both FTP and SFTP servers in same box. If yes how.
Please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. These are two different services. The only limitation is that the different services can't use the same port. The default FTP port is `21`, while the SFTP connection goes through the SSH port (connection), that by default is `22`.

By default Ubuntu Server comes with `openssh-server` enabled, and the SFTP service is also enabled by default via the configuration file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. So if you are able to establish a ssh connection, you must be able to [use SFTP](https://askubuntu.com/a/987775/566421) by the same credentials.

There are many FTP servers that you can install, probably the most popular is `vsftpd`, that allows to setup a secure encrypted connection (by default FTP is not secure enough). Here are few manuals:

- [Ubuntu Documentation: FTP Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ftp-server.html)
- [Digital ocean: How To Set Up vsftpd for a User's Directory on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [TechMint: How to Install and Configure FTP Server in Ubuntu](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ftp-server-in-ubuntu/)